# How to set width in CSS class programatically with GWT?

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, gxt

I am working on GWT app and I have a bug: my button browse(which is FileUploadField class) has bigger width than normal, take a look:

[image]

When I do inspect element and set width to element to 20 px everything is ok. But I don't know how to set programmatically in GWT(name of that class in CSS is "x-form-file"), I tried with some solutions from internet like:

```
 fileUploadField = new FileUploadField();
        fileUploadField.setAllowBlank(false);
        fileUploadField.setName("uploadedFile");
        fileUploadField.setFieldLabel("File");
        fileUploadField.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("width", "20px");
```

but without success. Could someone helps me how to get that class in css programatically in my gwt code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a CSS Client bundle (an interface), something like this :

```
interface MyCss extends CssResource {
  String className();
}
```

After that you need to have this bundle inside your class as an instance variable:

@UiField
MyCss style;

then in your code you can add the style using:
fileUploadField.addStyleName(style.className())

Working with css in the code is somehow boilerplate, for detailed example check GWT website: [LINK](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResourceCookbook)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can add `.x-form-file { width :20px;}` to your project's style.css this will override the style.
2. you can try: `fileUploadField.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(20, Unit.PX);`

Raz